# Web Service does not contain operation - it does, but it starts with an upper case letter

Tags: java, web-services, spring, wsdl

I am trying to write a SOAP Client for KashFlow which has this WSDL:

https://securedwebapp.com/api/service.asmx

It uses soapenc, so I can't use JAXB (and wsimport) as I'd prefer, and so need to use JAX-RPC. I have managed to create Java classes with wscompile and also the Eclipse Apache Axis plugin.

I am using Spring and the JaxRpcPortProxyFactoryBean

```
<bean id="kashflowWebService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.JaxRpcPortProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="kashflow.axisapi.KashFlowAPI"/>
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="https://securedwebapp.com/api/service.asmx?WSDL"/>
    <property name="namespaceUri" value="KashFlow"/>
    <property name="serviceName" value="KashFlowAPI"/>
    <property name="portName" value="KashFlowAPISoap"/> 
</bean>
```

This all seems fine up to a point, it is finding the service and the port. I have a request for the GetCurrencies operation, which is a simple operation that requires only the username and password. But this returns the following error:

```
Caused by: port: {KashFlow}KashFlowAPISoap does not contain operation: getCurrencies
```

The operation is there but called "GetCurrencies". In the generated classes the embedded String literals all seem to start with uppercase, so why does the error mention the operation starting with lower case? Something to do with expecting the WSDL to match Java method naming conventions?

As I understand it the operation is case sensitive, and that if you were making a WSDL for Java consumption you would make your operations start with lowercase, but I think that the service was written for .NET and they provide samples for C#, PHP etc but none for Java.

I have tried two different sets of generated code (wscompile and Axis wsdl2java) and will try to change the Spring JAX-RPC to some other method to see if that helps.

How can I force this to use the operation's proper name as defined in the WSDL that I provided?

Comment: Seems to be to do with Spring - having gone "back to basics" using the code generated by wscompile I have been able to access the web service.